# What would be a reason for msbuild yo put out different output locally on my computer than on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, continuous-integration

I run msbuild on a solution that has multiple web projects locally and also on Azure DevOps build pipeline. When I run it locally I get ~140 files(the correct files) in the output, when I run it in DevOps I get ~1.9k files. below is the command I am running. I tried looking at the .csproj file and also the publishprofile file and didn't see anything of.

```
.\msbuild.exe "C:\[SolutionDir]\[SolutionName].sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:PublishProfile="Release" /p:OutDir="bin/CI-Release"
```

Anyone know what would be the reason for this?

Comment: Hello @hakubex -

 Did you do a code checkout and if you did so, it will also be passed to the output. 

Try reviewing the files on the output and try to match it up with the code.

Comment: the 140 files is the correct output. I have no idea where the 1.9k files came from

Comment: Hi @hakubex, The output file contain some packages, if it already exists locally, it will not be generated again, please clean the local cache and try it again. In the Azure DevOps, if you are using self-hosted agent, please also clean the agent cache folder. By the way, do you use the copy file task to copy the files and then upload these as output files?

If the issue still occurs, since we do not know the output file content, could you package the output files and share it here?

Comment: Hi @Hakubex, Is there any update for this issue?

Comment: i tried a "nuget locals all -clear" and it didn't work. I compared my .csproj files agaisnt my packages.config files and noticed they didn't match when it came to references. I never really cared to notice but is this normal?